# Understanding the subtle difference in calculating percentile

Tags: python, numpy, percentile

When calculating the percentile using `numpy`, I see some authors use:

```
Q1, Q3 = np.percentile(X, [25, 75])
```

which is clear to me. However, I also see others use:

```
loss = np.percentile(X, 4)
```

I presume 4 implies dividing the 100 into 4 percentiles but how the loss is calculated here (i.e., in the second case)?

Comment: Do you have any more context with regards to the uses of the first and second parts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know where you found the second case but it's incorrect (or misinterpreted).

`np.percentile(X, 4)` simply calculates the 4th percentile.

```
X = np.arange(0, 101)

np.percentile(X, [25, 75])
# array([25., 75.])

np.percentile(X, 4)
# 4.0
```